# Can you buy Foreign Tourist Quota tickets at Vasco Da Gama railway station?

Tags: trains, india

Is it possible to buy Indian Foreign Tourist Quota railway tickets at the Vasco Da Gama railway station? This post from 2012 says it is possible, however mentions restrictions on tickets at Madgaon, and was wondering if a similar restriction applied to tickets purchased at Vasco Da Gama... http://www.indiamike.com/india/indian-railways-f10/booking-offices-for-foreign-tourist-quota-in-goa-t166621/

Comment: https://erail.in/info/ticket-booking-foreign-tourist/207

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can (I did so yesterday), for any train in India, as of April 2014.

There is no separate queue for foreign tourists, you have to wait in line at the "Reservation Office". Expect to spend 30-45 minutes in line. While you are waiting ask the ticket agents for the form, you can fill out your train/address details on the form which will speed up the process once you get to the front (and make the people behind you happier).

You must bring your passport. You can pay in rupees.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can do it online on irctc.co.in website.
But ideally you should Sign-up on irctc website before flying to India, as it will verify your non-Indian mobile number.
More info: https://erail.in/info/ticket-booking-foreign-tourist/207